# Bounds on the determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $$B = A + \epsilon I$$

where $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, $I$ is an identity matrix and $\epsilon$ is a positive scalar.

Is there a lower bound on the determinant of $B$?

If A is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix (say a co-variance matrix), is there a lower bound, when $\epsilon$ is a positive?

Comment: $\operatorname{det}(B)$ is a continuous function of $\epsilon$, and you're not assuming _anything_ about $A$, so, no, there's no lower bound on the determinant of $B$.  Why do you think there might be?

Comment: Are you thinking of $A$ as fixed?  Then your question makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added a second part to my question for when A is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If A is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix (say a co-variance matrix), is there a lower bound, when $\epsilon$ is a positive?

Given that the determinant is a product of all the eigenvalues of a matrix, that a positive semidefinite matrix has only nonnegative eigenvalues $\lambda_k(A) \ge 0$, that $\lambda_k(A + \epsilon I) = \lambda_k(A) + \epsilon$, and that $\epsilon \ge 0$, the lower bound is $\det A$ (for $\epsilon = 0$).

Comment: So for a non-zero $\epsilon$, $\epsilon > 0$, the lower bound is $\det A + \epsilon^n$, where $n$ is the dimensionality of $A$. Correct?

Comment: No. If the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_k$, then $\det(A + \epsilon I) = \prod_{k=1}^n (\lambda_k + \epsilon)$. The bound for that is $\inf_\epsilon \det(A + \epsilon I) = \det A$.

Comment: Oh yes, that was a stupid error I did. But thanks, I got what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The way your question is posed, there is no lower bound. Simply choose $A=(c-\epsilon)I$ with arbitrary $c$ and your matrix will have determinant $c^3$, which runs through $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the determinant can take any value.

Or maybe, you want a lower bound in terms of the determinant of $A$? In that case, you can always just transform A into Jordan form (I won't be affected) and just read off the determinant. This should also (given some knowledge about $A$) give you lower bounds.

For instance, it's clear that $\operatorname{det} B=0$ is always possible, regardless of the determinant of $A$ (you only need one entry $-\epsilon$ on the diagonal of $A$), so a lower bound must be $<0$. If the determinant is not zero, it will be a polynomial in $\epsilon$, which should give you some real bounds given some assumptions on $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin. It makes sense. Is there a lower bound for the special case when A is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix? I have modified my question to add this second part.